# How can convert query string in laravel to json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem here, I want to change the query string that I received to the json form as follows

```
{"id":"89"}
```

here I try to use json_encode but the one it produces is

```
""?id=89""
```

here is my code

```
    $coba = str_replace($request->url(), '',$request->fullUrl());
        if (empty($coba)) {
           $url = "{}";
        } else {
            $url = $coba;
        }

         $json_body = json_encode($url);
```

there I also want to change if there is no query string then the result is {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you for both conditions:

```
json_encode($request->query(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

[PHP Manual - JSON Functions - `json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Requests - Retrieving Input - Retrieving Input From The Query String](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) `query`

Comment: well it works, but what if there is no query string condition then it generates {}

Answer (score 0):

```
//get Parameters
$array = [
    'id' => 20,
    'name' => 'john',
];
//getting the current url from Request
$baseUrl = $request->url();

//we are encoding the array because 
//u said that the get parms in json format
//so that ...
$json = json_encode($array);

//now building the query based on the data
//from json by decoding it
$query = (http_build_query(json_decode($json)));

//at the end of the url you need '?' mark so...
$url = \Illuminate\Support\Str::finish($baseUrl,'?');
//now Merging it
$fullUrl = $url.$query;

dump($fullUrl);
```

For any issues kindly comment